# Get java Managed Bean start time

Tags: java, javabeans

Is there a way I can obtaing the time when a bean was initialized?

I can only fin examples how to get the JVM startup time but I need to also know the difference between the JVM startup time and a bean startup time.

I can't find in the documentation anything that I can use, except for writing something to hold the start time value for a bean.

Does anyone know if there is an existing method I could use to get that?

Comment: Depending on the use case I'd use a profiler, or a micro benchmark using JMH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring doesn't store it by itself.

You can add custom code to store it. Just add method with `@PostConstruct` annotation to your bean and save time in it.